# Prove that there exists a sequence $(a_n)$ in $l^1$ such that $\sum_{n} a_n f_n $ not in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Suppose $\{f_n\} \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ satisfy $\sup_{n} |f_n(x)| < +\infty$ a.e. and $\sup_{n} \Vert f_n\Vert_{L^1} = +\infty$. Prove that there exists a sequence $(a_n)$ in $l^1$such that $\sum_{n} a_n f_n $ not in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

This is an exercise of functional analysis, so I was thinking using tools like Uniform Boundedness Principle. For each $x$ there is an operator $T_x$ that maps every $l^1$ sequence $(a_n)$ to $(a_n f_n(x))$, and its norm is $\sup_{n} |f_n(x)|$. But I can't see how to show the contradiction. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose not. Then the operator $T:\ell^1\to L^1(\Bbb R)$, $(a_n)_n\mapsto \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nf_n$ is defined on all of $\ell^1$ and it has closed graph (use the first assumption for this), so the closed graph theorem implies that $T$ is bounded. But this contradicts the second assumption as $\lVert Te_n\rVert=\lVert f_n\rVert$ is an unbounded sequence in $L^1(\Bbb R)$ while $(e_n)_n$ is bounded in $\ell^1$.

Answer (score 1):

Define $T_N:\ell^{1}\to L^{1}(\mathbb R)$ by $T_N((a_n))= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} a_nf_n(x)$. Let us compute the norm of this operator:

Clearly, $\|T_n\|\leq \sup_{\{1\leq n\le N\}} \|f_n\|_1$. Note that $T_N(1,0,0,...)=f_1$ so $\|T_n\|\ge \|f_1\|_1$. Similarly, $\|T_n\|\ge \|f_i\|_1$ for each $i$. Now you can complete the proof using uniform Boundenness Principle to the sequence $(T_N)$.

Comment: I suppose $\Vert T_N \Vert$ is just equal to $\sup_{n\leq N} \Vert f_n\Vert_1$，so $\sup_{N}\Vert T_N \Vert = +\infty$ implies there exists $x\in l^1$ such that $\sup_{N}\Vert T_N x\Vert = +\infty$,  but it's saying $\sup_N\int_{\mathbb{R}} \vert \sum_{n\leq N}a_n f_n\vert = +\infty$,  does it imply $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \vert \sum_{n}a_n f_n\vert = +\infty$?  What if I choose $(a_n)$ and $(f_n)$ carefully such that $\sum_{n\leq N}a_n f_n = N^2 \chi_{[0,\frac{1}{N}]}$.